# Add multiple forign Keys same forign key in other entity C#

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity

I have two tables and I want two foreign keys with one table.
I am able to make 2 foreign keys, but when I insert data it throws an exception.

The scenario is like this:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid images (can't copy and paste for a test) and show the code: including sufficient of the model to re-create. But most importantly what exception?

Comment: *but when I insert data it throws an exception* -- Please just imagine someone else saying that to you. Then edit your question and add the details you'd ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be from :

- First check two table in SQL server and draw up diagram and input test data in two tables.
- Second check data with the query (`select * from tbl1. ... join ...`) and your code.